Is it possible that Azure devops backlogs view will show testcases as well?
I would like to see testcases on the backlog view but it is not showing even though they are linked. Is there a way to make them appear on the backlog views?
I've tried to google it without any success, so does this exist or do I need to create a feature request?

You can add the Test Case type to the "Iteration backlog" in the process, then you let it  display on the backlogs view. For more details, you can see the steps in my answer below. @Drdrn

Only the work items set as "Portfolio backlogs", "Requirement backlog" or "Iteration backlog" in the process can be displayed on the backlogs view.
To let test cases can be displayed on the backlogs view, you can do like as below:

Ensure you are using an inherited process so that you can make customizations in the process.

Open the inherited process and go to "Backlog levels" tab. If you want to  set the the Test Case type work items as the child of User Story and can be displayed on the backlogs view, add Test Case to "Iteration backlog".


Go the project which is using the inherited process. You can either link the existing test cases as Child of a user story or directly add new test cases as the Child of a user story. And the test cases can be displayed as linked Child items of the user story on the backlogs view.





@Drdrn, You're welcome. And glad that my answer can help you.
